# Unable to use yum on CentOS 7

Tags: linux, centos

I have install CentOS 7 on hyper-v successfully, but when I try to update using yum update or try to install using the `yum` command I have the below error:

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks Could not retrieve mirrorlist
http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=7&arch=x86_64&repo=os&infra=stock
error was 12: Timeout on
http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=7&arch=x86_64&repo=os&infra=stock:
(28, 'Resolving timed out after 30425 milliseconds')


One of the configured repositories failed (Unknown),  and yum doesn't
have enough cached data to continue. At this point the only  safe
thing yum can do is fail. There are a few ways to work "fix" this:

      1. Contact the upstream for the repository and get them to fix the problem.

      2. Reconfigure the baseurl/etc. for the repository, to point to a working
         upstream. This is most often useful if you are using a newer
         distribution release than is supported by the repository (and the
         packages for the previous distribution release still work).

      3. Disable the repository, so yum won't use it by default. Yum will then
         just ignore the repository until you permanently enable it again or use
         --enablerepo for temporary usage:

             yum-config-manager --disable <repoid>

      4. Configure the failing repository to be skipped, if it is unavailable.
         Note that yum will try to contact the repo. when it runs most commands,
         so will have to try and fail each time (and thus. yum will be be much
         slower). If it is a very temporary problem though, this is often a nice
         compromise:

             yum-config-manager --save --setopt=<repoid>.skip_if_unavailable=true

 Cannot find a valid baseurl for repo: base/7/x86_64`
```

Answer (score 7):

> `(28, 'Resolving timed out after 30425 milliseconds')`

That means your VM probably lacks a working DNS server. Resolving here refers to resolving a domain name to an IP address.

Try pinging google.com or mirrorlist.centos.org to see if you have any DNS functionality. The currently used DNS servers are listed in **/etc/resolv.conf** like so:

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

If the **/etc/resolv.conf** file is empty, try first pinging the IP addresses above (Google's public DNS) and then add them to the **/etc/resolv.conf** file as above to start using Google DNS. To make this a permanent fix you may want to use the CentOS 7 network config tool to set up DNS servers properly. Here's a decent article on how to do it: http://www.krizna.com/centos/setup-network-centos-7/

Comment: the /etc/resolve.conf already using 8.8.8.8 adn 8.8.4.4 . the internet access working fine and i can ping to http://mirrorlist.centos.org. It is not the network access problem

Comment: Please try running `curl 'http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=7&arch=x86_64&repo=os&infra=stock'` and see if you get a list of URLs. According to yum, this is the equivalent of the command it's trying to run and that command is timing out. This is why I'd like to test whether or not your DNS configuration can resolve mirrorlist.centos.org to its IPs, and later connect to that site to get the list of repos.

Comment: curl 'http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=7&arch=x86_64&repo=os&infra=stock'
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: mirrorlist.centos.org; Unknown error
[root@ayope network-scripts]# curl http://mirrorlist.centos.org
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: mirrorlist.centos.org; Unknown error

Comment: Hmm... DNS is failing. How about `host mirrorlist.centos.org`?

Comment: ping mirrorlist.centos.orgPING mirrorlist.centos.org (108.61.16.227) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 108-61-16-227.constant.com (108.61.16.227): icmp_seq=1 ttl=56 time=264 ms
64 bytes from 108-61-16-227.constant.com (108.61.16.227): icmp_seq=2 ttl=56 time=266 ms

Comment: host mirrorlist.centos.org
mirrorlist.centos.org has address 84.22.180.89
mirrorlist.centos.org has address 88.150.173.218
mirrorlist.centos.org has address 108.61.16.227
mirrorlist.centos.org has IPv6 address 2a02:2498:1:3d:5054:ff:fed3:e91a

Comment: OK, so DNS works, since host and ping can get to it... Sometimes an incorrect network interface setup can break things in really weird ways. Can you check the contects of `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0` to make sure they make sense? If things look OK, try switching to a static IP address if possible.

Answer (score 1):

Use `ip route` to see to which IP default route is going, if nothing get visible, then you need to get fresh IP which can be done by

```
sudo dhclient
```

This must resolve issue. Try `yum update` now.

Answer (score 0):

Its the ipv6 problem. Disable the ipv6 from runnig.

```
lsmod | grep -i ipv6
sysctl --all
nslookup google.com
systemctl stop NetworkManager
systemctl disable NetworkManager
cd /etc/default

change line to : GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="ipv6.disable=1 rd.lvm.lv=centos/swap vconsole.font=latarcyrh

grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg
vi grub
ip addr
```

note : add disable commang on grub

Answer (score 0):

Locate the "/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-enp0s17" file. **File name may vary based on env. 
1.Locate lines:
BOOTPROTO=none
ONBOOT=no

2. change to 
   BOOTPROTO=dhcp
   ONBOOT=yes
   save + exit
3. run "systemctl restart network"